# Как ловить фатальные ошибки?

Tags: php, исключения

Какой класс исключений использовать для перехвата фатальных ошибок, например, при попытке вывода несуществующей переменной? Есть общее представление, но хотелось бы на конкретном примере увидеть

Comment: Отсутствие переменной не является фатальной ошибкой, а всего лишь предупреждением. Но суть понятно, в 7 версии php немного поменялся механизм исключений. Туда добавили, в частности, ошибки интерпретации. Такое теперь тоже можно перехватывать. Делается стандартно через try catch